# How to remove the ETag header from the response served by the FileServer

Tags: go, http, response-headers, buffalo

How Can i remove the "ETag" response header which is set in  gobuffalo fileServer ?

I have tried creating a middleware function :

```
func RemoveETagHeader(next buffalo.Handler) buffalo.Handler {
    return func(c buffalo.Context) error {
        // Run the next handler in the chain
        err := next(c)

        // Remove the ETag header from the response
        c.Response().Header().Del("ETag")

        return err
    }
}
```

and then using it like this:

```
func App() *buffalo.App {

app = buffalo.New(buffalo.Options{
// ....
}
app.Use(middleware.RemoveETagHeader)
    return app
}
```

but the ETag has not been removed from the response

Comment: How do you server files using gobuffalo? [This](https://github.com/gobuffalo/buffalo/blob/6f2bafeb55368d88f17b63dea10d569036ff85fd/route_mappings.go#L93) suggests that if you run `App.ServeFiles(...)` no middleware is involved in request handling. All-in-all, I suggest you to just debug the (gobuffalo) code as it's open source after all.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it like this, once you write into the Writer, the header is set.

What you can do, is wrap the context and delete the header when `Response` is called:

```golang
type deleteHeaderContext struct {
    buffalo.Context
}

func (c deleteHeaderContext) Response() http.ResponseWriter {
    res := c.Context.Response()
    res.Header().Del("ETag")
    return c.Context.Response()
}

func RemoveETagHeader(next buffalo.Handler) buffalo.Handler {
    return func(c buffalo.Context) error {
        c = deleteHeaderContext{c}
        err := next(c)
        
        return err
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But i can't find a way of applying middleware (RemoveETagHeader) when gobuffulo serves files from a hard drive with the fileServer.